# Why does Nginx's new files' permissions supersede my default ACL

Tags: nginx, permissions, cache, access-control-list

I have issues setting up proper permission on cache directory on a site that run on Debian 10 with Nginx and php-fpm.

I have an user 'myuser' which home is /var/www/mydomain.tld
The strucure of the directory is:

```
drwxr-x---  2 myuser myuser 4096 Jan  3 20:24 backups/
drwxrwx---+ 4 myuser myuser 4096 Jan  5 21:10 cache/
drwxr-x---+ 2 myuser myuser 4096 Jan  5 00:00 logs/
drwxr-x---  5 myuser myuser 4096 Jan  3 20:27 public/
```

I configured a fpm pool to use this user and added Nginx to myuser's group.
I also added write permission on cache dir for group so that Nginx can write in there.
Finally I set up some acl on the directory to grant write access to myuser on the files created by Nginx.

```
# file: var/www/domain.tld/cache
# owner: myuser
# group: myuser
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:myuser:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

But when Nginx creates some directories myuser cannot access to it.
The created directories don't inherit the default mask and use '---' instead, leaving my acl inoperative.

```
drwx------+ 3 nginx nginx 4096 Jan  6 18:55 3
drwx------+ 3 nginx nginx 4096 Jan  6 19:16 9
drwx------+ 3 nginx nginx 4096 Jan  6 18:55 d

# file: var/www/domain.tld/cache/d
# owner: nginx
# group: nginx
user::rwx
user:myuser:rwx     #effective:---
group::rwx          #effective:---
mask::---
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:myuser:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

What am i missing here ?

Comment: you may need to check Nginx's umask settings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584021/nginx-php-fpm-umask-setting